# Attribute table : How to select more then one feature?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select, expression

I have a vector layer: ROADS that is composed of different types of roads: primary, secondary, tertiary, trunk, etc.

When I right click on the layer ROADS and I go to Attribute table -> Select by expression -> the column where I want to do the selection: highway -> I wrote this:

```
"highway" ILIKE '%primary%' OR "highway" ILIKE '%secondary%' OR "highway" ILIKE '%tertiary%' OR "highway" ILIKE '%trunk%' NOT "highway" ILIKE '%trunk_link%'
```

Till `NOT "highway" ILIKE '%trunk_link%'` the selection is working well. I can see all the roads that starts with primary, secondary, tertiary and trunk. So also trunk_link -> I don't want that. To erase it from the selection I add `NOT "highway" ILIKE '%trunk_link%'`. It didn't work -> suddenly I had O selected lines .

Do anyone knows the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to connect the parts with `AND` or `OR`.

```
(
     "highway" ILIKE '%primary%' 
  OR "highway" ILIKE '%secondary%' 
  OR "highway" ILIKE '%tertiary%' 
  OR "highway" ILIKE '%trunk%'
)
AND "highway" NOT ILIKE '%trunk_link%'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanx a lot. Basically I made two errors: 1) instead of AND I put NOT ; 2) instead of NOT ILIKE I put just NOT. I tryied without brackets and it works too.

Comment: You probably could also just do `... OR "highway" ILIKE 'trunk'` and forget about the last bit.

Comment: No no because I really don't want to see the the trunk_link feature. BTW I just tried to eliminate more then one feature from the selection (also secondary_link) and in that case the brackets are needed.

Comment: Sure, if there are also other `trunk%` attributes you are right. In general, try to use the `%` only where necessary, this way you are more precise and faster. I also usually just put some extra brackets even when not strictly required because I tend to forget if `AND` or `OR` takes precedence so I make the job easier for myself in the future.

Comment: I didn't accepted some answers? What does it mean? I didn't erase any answer..all of them are useful for me and I think that also to others with the same problem

Comment: OK I see, I just noticed the green check. I'll use it for the best answers then

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom right-hand corner of the 'select by expression' window, there is the 'select' button: pull the drop-down to reveal the 'remove from selection', 'add to selection', etc. That should do it.

Comment: Thanx for a quick response. I tryied but it didn't work. Already have a solution @Matthias